# Video player for Linux with playlist

Tags: linux, media-player

Yes, it's as simple as in the title.

The player should have a window for the video, obviously, but also have a playlist so that I can quickly switch between titles.

The purpose is to find scenes within a collection of videos.

VLC Media Player, for example, does not have a playlist.

Comment: Yes, VLC does have a playlist - View -> Playlist.

Answer (score 1):

As Sebastian suggests, VLC does have the ability to create and save playlists, which implies that one can play from a playlist.

Numerous answers with specifics can be found on the [SE for askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/645984/how-to-make-a-new-playlist-in-vlc-player-and-assign-songs)

Direct copies:

From user Vitrel:

> In VLC under "View", there you have an entry "Playlist". When you have
> organized you playlist you can save and name it with the following
> step: Under "Media" you have the entry "Save Playlist to File".

From user Maythux:

> You can use the shortcut Ctrl+L. This will open the playlist then
> right click Add File or you can Add all files from a specific
> directory using Add directory.

Other useful answers can be found from the above link.